# Why "avoid trivial, one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary"?

Tags: discussion

Why sholdn't the community welcome editing typos?

When I klick edit, a warning appears, asking me to "avoid trivial, one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary".

Is this to encourag the editor to come up with a non-trivial improvement, as long as they have the edit window open?

What is the preferred approch?

Would it be preferible to leave a comment? To flag the question? Ignore the typo?

Answer (score 6):

Good question. The issue has been [raised on the SO meta before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/139256), and the answers I can find are as follows:

- There's no limit to nitpicking, and if the question is understandable, then tiny fixes don't add much other than to satisfy our grammar Nazi neuroses.
- Editing the question bumps it back to the top of the page, which is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82295/139256).
- When the question has been edited by 5+ people, it becomes [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), which (among other things) means no one earns any rep from the question.

Comment: as pointed out on in the comments on the [SO meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74433/152246), such undesired side-effects of minor edits (bump, change to CW, etc., ), could be eliminated for minor edits (e.g. by having a check-box that says 'minor-edit')

Comment: @David - That definitely opens the door for abuse, but still, suggest it as a feature request on the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/139256) and see what people think.